# Windows 7 print option wizard rotate some photos from portrait to landscape, how to stop this?

Tags: windows-7, images, printer, print-to-pdf

Windows 7 print option wizard rotate some photos from portrait to landscape, how to stop this?

When i see photo in windows photo viewer it shows fine.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Click on the **Options** link (lower right-hand side of the window).

In the **Print Settings** window that appears, select **Printer Properties...**

[image]

In the **Microsoft Print to PDF Document Properties** window, select the desired final orientation (Portrait or Landscape) in the dropdown menu.

[image]

Comment: For me this rotates the image as well.

Comment: Also works in Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Windows takes into account the image dimensions. If the width is greater than the height it will rotate the image even if you change the paper orientation. So it doesn't let you print an image with those dimensions in portrait more without rotation. The easy solution is to give it more height than width if you want to print it in portrait mode or the other way around if you want landscape.